# Using PhysicsEditor to create unique bodies for collisions in box2d (AndEngine)

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, collision

I've been developing a game recently and I would like to incorporate pixel perfect collisions (so it ignores the alpha part of the image)

After doing some research I was referred to using the software PhysicsEditor for you to create unique bodies to use in box2d:

http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

the software itself is fine to use and I've got all .xml files ready to use and everything in my project set up

I've also been looking at the examples provided here:

https://github.com/ANDLABS-Git/AndEngine-PhysicsEditor-Extension-Examples/tree/master/src/org/andlabs/andengine/extension/physicsloader

My problem is I'm not entirely sure where to go from here to begin to detect collisions - I understand how basic box2d collisions work but I have no idea how to use anything created from PhysicsEditor

I'm very new to android programming so I don't quite understand how to use PhysicsEditor in my project and how to use what it's created as bodies that can be attached to sprites and such - (unless it's all included within the loader it's self?)

After I've used the loader (as seen in the example) - what do I do from here?

I can't seem to find any other examples of people using the PhysicsEditor with collisions in their project either so I'm stuck on what to do.

(I've also looked up other alternatives for perfect pixel collisions but they seem even more of a hassle to set up)

Any help would be appreciated and an example of a basic project using PhysicsEditor with collisions or some sort of tutorial for dummies would be ideal.

Thanks